# Именительный темы - не ошибка ли поставить 2 восклицательных знака?

Tags: пунктуация, именительный-темы

Здравствуйте.
На Тотальном диктанте я в именительном темы поставила 2 восклицательных знака. Вот так: Чусовская-Тагил! Солнечный поезд моего детства!
Не является ли это ошибкой?

Answer (score 5):

Во-первых, спорно, что это именительный темы, по–моему, просто назывное предложение, итог раздумий. Солнечный город моего детства и вовсе не может быть именительным темы, здесь информация о том, что этот маршрут является символом детства. Именительный темы информации не несёт, только называет тему: Зима. Крестьянин, торжествуя... Москва. Как много в этом слове...

Во-вторых, я не услышала здесь восклицания:

http://ulpressa.ru/2014/04/13/aleksey-ivanov-kogda-poezd-vernetsya-totalnyiy-diktant-v-ulyanovske/

Думаю, ошибка. Здесь или запятая, или многоточие: „Чусовская-Тагил“, солнечный поезд моего детства.

„Чусовская-Тагил“, солнечный поезд моего детства...

„Чусовская-Тагил“... Солнечный поезд моего детства...

Comment: Заменил дефис и кавычки. http://meta.rus.stackexchange.com/q/43/177015

Comment: Людмила, как вы относитесь к подобным правкам Вашего текста? Мне кажется это не совсем корректно. Но если вы не возражаете, я, конечно, тоже возражать не буду.

Comment: Nick Volynkin, мы прекрасно обходились и обходимся без этих наворотов. А уж Людмила-то наверняка знает, где какие кавычки ставить.

Comment: Людмила, у Пушкина — "в этом звуке".

Comment: behemothus, спасибо за поддержку, но я действительно не возражаю.Если на этом сайте так строго с пробелами, формой кавычек - пусть правят, кому это надо, я знаю, что печатаю иногда "неряшливо", слежу только за ошибками, видимо, скоро  и этого не смогу - слепну, так что ради бога... Вот только не понимаю, зачем править ответы за 2013 год... Кстати, орфографические ошибки в ответах этого года не правят, а пробелы у тире и дефиса правят - наверно, это главнее. Я в давние ответы не заглядываю, новых вопросов достаточно. Вот и  Ваш комментарий только сегодня усмотрела - благодаря М_Г.

Comment: Уважаемый М_Г, да я и не цитировала Пушкина, там знаки препинания другие. У меня в голове тогда была дискуссия с товарищем о сочинениях в Интернете, где в названиях форумов используют известные высказывания, но на свой лад, одно из них - из "Онегина". http://forum-slovo.ru/index.php?topic=3194.20
https://narzur.ru/moskva-kak-mnogo-v-ehtom-slove/
https://ruslanviktorov.livejournal.com/17135.html. Вот и довозмущалась - в голове осталось то, что с форума, здесь конструкции параллельны. Мне же смысл нужен был. Так что уж извините...

Answer (score 0):

Преподаватель, который нам диктовала, сказала, что это именительный темы.

Answer (score 0):

Не вижу ошибки. Это как два предложения получается. В конце концов можно считать, что это два именительных темы. )))

Хотя не знаю, правильно ли тут вообще считать именетильным темы.

Comment: Мысль понятна. Только подробнее пишите,, а то Ваши даже содержательные ответы попадают в "сомнительные".